# How to read information of an array in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to loop an array and create list items out of it. In the console,it is showing mistake is thrown, because my array has no keys but only values. So What is the right operation to read out an array?

```
*// this.props.items = ["cars","streets","houses"];*Wrong. You can't update props

var TodoList = React.createClass({
 render: function() {
  var createItem = function(item) {
  return <li>{item}</li>;
  };
  return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
}
});
```

Comment: keys are required in your `<li>`s and they can be anything but should be unique for each child. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28329550/1642219

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```
this.filterOptions =['Monthly','Weekly','Daily'];

   <ul>
       {  this.filterOptions.map((filterItem) => {
       return (
                <li key={filterItem}>
                    <span>{filterItem}</span>
                 </li>
              );
          })
       }
     </ul>
```

EDIT 1: If there is duplicate value in array,

```
   <ul>
       {  this.filterOptions.map((filterItem,index) => {
       return (
                <li key={index}>//key must be uniq
                    <span>{filterItem}</span>
                 </li>
              );
          })
       }
     </ul>
```

Comment: You could also do `.map((filterItem, i) => { return (<li key={i}> ...`

Comment: @Chris yes. It will be useful when we have duplicate value.

Comment: Is there a missing closing brackets ((filterItem,index) ?

Comment: No. it is closed after return.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify because i see u use:

```
  var TodoList = React.createClass({
```

instead of

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
```

and the question about the closing brackets in the comments above:
  "Is there a missing closing brackets ((filterItem,index)""

i assume you are not using the es6 syntax, so i wanted to point out that

```
{ this.filterOptions.map(function(filterItem, index) {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
          <span>{filterItem}</span>
       </li>
    )
  }, this)
}
```

equals

```
{ this.filterOptions.map((filterItem,index) => {
   return (
      <li key={index}>
          <span>{filterItem}</span>
       </li>
    );
  })
}
```